# C# COM server returning E_POINTER from GetIDsOfNames

Tags: c#, comobject, idispatch, ole-automation

I'm trying to create a COM server in C# to expose an OLE automation object. I'd like to implement the IDispatch interface manually, since I need to do some amount of dynamic lookup for the members. When i call my custom `GetIDsOfNames` the C# method runs, and then the client errors with `E_POINTER`. But lets start at the start

After hours of reading and no small amount of trial and error, I've managed to cobble something together i would think should work. I have a very simple interface

```
[Guid("7B95C174-9320-4400-88AB-6960B019CEDE")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ISimpleObject {
    EchoObject testNest();
}
```

That can return another COM object. This first COM object uses the default C# IDispatch implementation and works fine. The `EchoObject` is the one with the custom IDispatch implementation, since that's not part of the C# SDK let's look at how I've defined it

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDispatch {
    int GetTypeInfoCount(out uint pctinfo);
    int GetTypeInfo(uint iTInfo, int lcid, out IntPtr info);

    int GetIDsOfNames(
        ref Guid iid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 2)] string[] names,
        int cNames,
        int lcid,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeParamIndex = 2)] int[] rgDispId);

    int Invoke(
        int dispId,
        ref Guid riid,
        int lcid,
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.INVOKEKIND wFlags,
        ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DISPPARAMS pDispParams,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] object[] result,
        IntPtr pExcepInfo,
        IntPtr puArgErr);
}
```

I use the defined IDispatch interface in the definition of the IEchoObject interface.

```
[Guid("D3E9B530-DFD5-4B54-88B9-4FBC8B0926E2")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IEchoObject: IDispatch {
    string testint();
}
```

The implementation of this interface then has to implement ICustomQueryInterface to allow the IDispatch casting to take place.

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IDispatch))]
[Guid("F625A833-3B4E-455D-90A9-89B1953147CD"), ComVisible(true)]
public class EchoObject : ReferenceCountedObject, IEchoObject, ICustomQueryInterface {
    public CustomQueryInterfaceResult GetInterface(ref Guid iid, out IntPtr ppv) {
        Console.WriteLine("Are we a: " + iid + "?");
        ppv = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (typeof(IDispatch).GUID == iid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
            ppv = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IDispatch), CustomQueryInterfaceMode.Ignore);
            return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.Handled;
        }
        return CustomQueryInterfaceResult.NotHandled;
    }

    public int GetIDsOfNames(
        ref Guid iid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 2)] string[] names,
        int cNames,
        int lcid,
        [Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeParamIndex = 2)] int[] rgDispId
    ) {
        bool unknown = false;

        if(cNames == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting id of " + names[0]);
            if (names[0] == "testman") {
                Console.WriteLine("Member found");
                rgDispId[0] = 1;
            } else {
                rgDispId[0] = -1;
            }
        }

        return unknown ? HRESULT.DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME : HRESULT.S_OK;
    }
}
```

I have of course implemented the other methods of IDispatch, but i don't believe them to be important to the problem I'm having. Notice that the GetIDsOfNames prints to console.

I can create the initial `SimpleObject` just fine. I can also call the `testNest` method on it and get the `EchoObject` instance. When looking up the ID of the `testman` method on that `EchoObject` though, the client gets back a `E_POINTER` (Invalid Pointer) from win32 instead of the result.

I have tested it with from Excel, VBScript, and a custom C++ COM client. All get an *Invalid Pointer* error, and the C++ client shows that it's from `GetIDsOfNames`. Oddly enough though, the C# method runs, it happily prints the line to console, returns, and then the C++ COM client gets an error.

If disable all my custom IDispatch and instead use the default C# implementation (calling the testint method instead of testman) it works fine. I suspect my Marshaling might be wrong somewhere, but I've been staring at it for hours and I can't see the problem.

EDIT: I did another test. If i change the return type of GetIDsOfNames from int to void it works. What's going on there? According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-getidsofnames) the return type is HRESULT (a 32 bit signed int) but when i return that i get an error.

Comment: @HansPassant In general you're probably right, but for my usecase I don't know what methods are available at compile time, so i need to look them up at runtime. That's not possible with the automatic IDispatch implementation. The IReflect interface is also not suitable since i still need to know all the methods i can provide at startup.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand how i can be wrong about my own requirements. I'm implementing a proxy between COM and some external system. I don't know which methods the objects of this external system has, but if I have a name i can go out and ask it if it has that particular member. I do not know of any way i can implement this without implementing IDispatch myself. The default IDispatch implementation only answers to members known at compile time (they have to be defined in the interface).